# How to keep a program going if a non number is typed in console

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, console, java.util.scanner

This is a connect four game, and if the user types in a number 1-7 then a disc is placed on a board. If the number is not 1-7, "try again" pops up. But, when the user types in a letter or a symbol, an exception comes up. 
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class ConnectFour{

   public static void main(String[] args){
      //board
      DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(550,550);
      int rowAvailable;
      Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
      g.drawLine(0,0,0,427);
      g.drawLine(0,0,500,0);
      g.drawLine(500,0,500,427);
      g.drawLine(0,427,500,427);
      for(int i = 0; i< 6; i++){
         for(int j= 0; j<= 6; j++){
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillRect(j*71,i*71,71,71);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillOval(j*71,i*71,71,71); 
         }
      }

      //setBlankArray
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      char[][] board = new char[6][7];
      for(int j = 0;j <= 6; j++){
         for(int i= 0; i < 6; i++){
            board[i][j] = ' ';
         }
      }
      boolean isBlack = true;
      boolean isRed = false;
      int column = 0;
      boolean playersTurn = true;
      boolean rightNum = false;

      //oneTurn
      while(getWinner(board, playersTurn)){
      //while(playersTurn == true){
         rightNum = false;
         if(isBlack == true){
            // displayCurrentPlayer
            System.out.println("Black's Turn");
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString("Red Disc's Turn",200, 450);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString("Black Disc's Turn",200, 450);
         }
         else{
            // displayCurrentPlayer
            System.out.println("Red's Turn");
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString("Black Disc's Turn",200, 450);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawString("Red Disc's Turn",200, 450);
         }
         System.out.print("Choose a column to place your disk (1-7): ");
         while(rightNum == false){
            column = (console.nextInt()) -1;
            if(column >= 0 && column < 7 && board[0][column] == ' '){
               rightNum = true;
            }
            else{
               System.out.print("Try again: ");
            }
         }

         drawBoard(column, board, isBlack, isRed, board, g);
         isBlack = !isBlack;
      }
      if(isBlack == false){
         System.out.println("Congratulations Black Player");

      }
      else
         {System.out.println("Congratulations Red Player");
      }
      // use the while loop to say try again if the column is filled.
   }

   public static void drawBoard(int column, char[][] board, boolean isBlack, boolean isRed, char[][] availability,Graphics g){

      char player = ' ';
      if(isBlack == true){
         g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         player = 'b';
      }
      else{
         g.setColor(Color.RED);
         player = 'r';
      }
      int x = 0;
      int row = 5;
      while(board[row-x][column] != ' '){
         x++;
      }
      row = row-x;
      g.fillOval((column * 71),(row * 71), 71,71);
      board[row][column] = player;
   }

   public static boolean getWinner(char[][] board, boolean playersTurn){
      int verticalCount = 0;
      boolean isVertical = false;
      for(int i = 0; i <= board[0].length - 1; i++){
         verticalCount = 0;                               
         for(int j = board.length - 1; j > 0; j--){
            if(board[j][i] == board[j-1][i] && board[j][i] != ' '){
               verticalCount++;
            } else {
               verticalCount = 0;
            }

            if(verticalCount == 3){
               isVertical = true;
            }
         }
      }

      int horizontalCount = 0;
      boolean isHorizontal = false;
      for(int i = board.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
         for(int j = 0 ; j < board[0].length-1; j++){
            if(board[i][j] == board[i][j+1] && board[i][j] != ' '){
               horizontalCount++;
            }
            else{
               verticalCount = 0;
            } 
            if(horizontalCount == 3){
               isHorizontal = true;
            }
         }
      }

      int diagonalCount = 0;
      boolean isDiagonal = false; 
     // for(int i = 0; i<=6; i++){
      //   for(int j =0; j<6; j++){
       //     if(board[i][j-1] == board[i][j]){
       //        diagonalCount++;
         //   } 
        // }
     // }

      if(isVertical || isHorizontal || isDiagonal){
         playersTurn = false;
      }
      else{
         playersTurn = true;}
      return playersTurn;
   }
}
```

Comment: You **want** the program to throw an exception when a non-numerical character is entered or it does it currently and you want to change that?

Answer (score 3):

Your code expects an integer when you use `console.nextInt()`

Use `hasNextInt()` to determine if the next character inline is an int if not then skip that character with `next()`

```
if(console.hasNextInt()){
     column = (console.nextInt()) -1;
     /* ... */
} else {
    console.next();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method [nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) throws :

- InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
- NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
- IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed

Your case should throws the first exception `InputMismatchException`, so you have just to use `try{` `catch` block:

```
while(rightNum == false){
            try{
            column = (console.nextInt()) -1;
            if(column >= 0 && column < 7 && board[0][column] == ' '){
               rightNum = true;
             }
            }catch(InputMismatchException ime)
            {
               //do nothing because it will achieve the else block
            }
```

Comment: You should move that `if` statement into the `try` or add a `continue` to the `catch`. Otherwise you will get some bugs when whatever was left in `column` hits that `if`.

Comment: @ChrisStillwell he initialized `column` with 0, but your suggetion is safer anyway, thank you.

Comment: Yes but it was initialized outside the loops and neither of you are resetting it anywhere. So if you enter an illegal character your move becomes the last move played.

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate your input:

```
// check that an int in inputted.
 if (console.hasNextInt()==true){
  // add validation for number range 
  // or some other such algorithm
    if (console.nextInt()>1= &&console.nextInt()<8){
        column = (console.nextInt()) -1;
   //etc
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29

Also, it is unnecessary to post all your code. Just the relevant pieces.